# ionic 3 cordova ios build failed 'google/protobuf/Api.pbobjc.h' file not found

Tags: ios, cordova, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm trying to build my ios ionic cordova app, but I have errors after `make pod install` (podfile installs firebasemessaging 2.0.0 and dependencies includes protobuf 3.5.0)

```
fatal error: 'google/protobuf/Api.pbobjc.h' file not found
 #import "google/protobuf/Api.pbobjc.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

** BUILD FAILED **

> The following build commands failed:
>           CompileC /var/root/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Monitoreo_de_viajes-glbzeqldfofumbcfnebzzlyuslmv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Protobuf.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Any.pbobjc.o
>   Protobuf/objectivec/google/protobuf/Any.pbobjc.m normal x86_64
>   objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
>           CompileC /var/root/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Monitoreo_de_viajes-glbzeqldfofumbcfnebzzlyuslmv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Protobuf.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Api.pbobjc.o
>   Protobuf/objectivec/google/protobuf/Api.pbobjc.m normal x86_64
>   objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
>           CompileC /var/root/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Monitoreo_de_viajes-glbzeqldfofumbcfnebzzlyuslmv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Protobuf.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Duration.pbobjc.o
>   Protobuf/objectivec/google/protobuf/Duration.pbobjc.m normal x86_64
>   objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
>           CompileC /var/root/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Monitoreo_de_viajes-glbzeqldfofumbcfnebzzlyuslmv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Protobuf.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Empty.pbobjc.o
>   Protobuf/objectivec/google/protobuf/Empty.pbobjc.m normal x86_64
>   objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (4 failures)
>   (node:31386) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error code 65 for
>   command: xcodebuild with args:
>   -xcconfig,/Users/danielvivas/Downloads/julianacg-allexxiamobileapp-c3cd5868890e/myApp/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-workspace,Monitoreo
>   de viajes.xcworkspace,-scheme,Monitoreo de
>   viajes,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphonesimulator,-destination,platform=iOS
>   Simulator,name=iPhone
>   X,build,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/danielvivas/Downloads/julianacg-allexxiamobileapp-c3cd5868890e/myApp/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/danielvivas/Downloads/julianacg-allexxiamobileapp-c3cd5868890e/myApp/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
>   (node:31386) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async
>   function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was
>   not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1) (node:31386) [DEP0018]
>   DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In
>   the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
>   Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

here is part of  config.xml

```
   <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.0.33:8100" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="^2.4.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" spec="^1.0.5" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="^1.1.4" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="^2.4.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.1" />
    <plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="^2.2.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-badge" spec="~0.8.5" />
    <plugin name="cordova-base64-to-gallery" spec="~4.1.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-android-permissions" spec="~1.0.0" />

    <plugin name="cordova-sqlite-storage" spec="^2.3.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-globalization" spec="^1.0.9" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="^2.4.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-sim" spec="^1.3.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^4.1.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-nativeaudio" spec="^3.0.9" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-shake" spec="^0.6.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" spec="^4.3.3" />
    <plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" spec="^2.0.0-rc4">
        <variable name="SENDER_ID" value="123456789" />
    </plugin>
    <engine name="android" spec="6.2.3" />
    <engine name="ios" spec="4.5.4" />
```

PODS FILE

```
# DO NOT MODIFY -- auto-generated by Apache Cordova
platform :ios, '8.0'
target 'MYPROJ' do
    project 'MYPROJ.xcodeproj'
    pod 'FirebaseMessaging', '~> 2.0.0'
end

podfile.lock

ODS:
  - FirebaseAnalytics (4.2.0):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 4.0)
    - FirebaseInstanceID (~> 2.0)
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/NSData+zlib (~> 2.1)
    - nanopb (~> 0.3)
  - FirebaseCore (4.0.20):
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/NSData+zlib (~> 2.1)
  - FirebaseInstanceID (2.0.10):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 4.0)
  - FirebaseMessaging (2.0.8):
    - FirebaseAnalytics (~> 4.0)
    - FirebaseCore (~> 4.0)
    - FirebaseInstanceID (~> 2.0)
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/Logger (~> 2.1)
    - Protobuf (~> 3.1)
  - GoogleToolboxForMac/Defines (2.1.4)
  - GoogleToolboxForMac/Logger (2.1.4):
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/Defines (= 2.1.4)
  - GoogleToolboxForMac/NSData+zlib (2.1.4):
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/Defines (= 2.1.4)
  - nanopb (0.3.8):
    - nanopb/decode (= 0.3.8)
    - nanopb/encode (= 0.3.8)
  - nanopb/decode (0.3.8)
  - nanopb/encode (0.3.8)
  - Protobuf (3.5.0)

DEPENDENCIES:
  - FirebaseMessaging (~> 2.0.0)

SPEC CHECKSUMS:
  FirebaseAnalytics: 7ef69e76a5142f643aeb47c780e1cdce4e23632e
  FirebaseCore: 90cb1c53d69b556f112a1bf72b5fcfaad7650790
  FirebaseInstanceID: 8d20d890d65c917f9f7d9950b6e10a760ad34321
  FirebaseMessaging: dfdcd307c2382290a1e297a81d0f18370f5b1bcd
  GoogleToolboxForMac: 91c824d21e85b31c2aae9bb011c5027c9b4e738f
  nanopb: 5601e6bca2dbf1ed831b519092ec110f66982ca3
  Protobuf: 8a9838fba8dae3389230e1b7f8c104aa32389c03

PODFILE CHECKSUM: e1ffdda9786de21eb39516a537d0b8f676809ccd
```

COCOAPODS: 1.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works when i have changed

```
<engine name="ios" spec="4.5.4" />
```

to

```
<engine name="ios" spec="4.4.0" />
```

in config.xml and re builded all (npm install, add platform ios, pod install)